# Why cannot used ~ symbol in bash script tell me the answer

Tags: unix

Why cannot used ~ symbol in bash script tell me the answer 
for example `cat ~/test/file.1`

Comment: -1 Punctuation, grammar, missing "thanks" or "please", imperative form ...

Comment: Note @opalenzuela that "thanks", etc are not entirely needed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts although I agree with you in the punctuation aspect.

Comment: Are you trying to use it literally, or do you want it to expand to the home directory?

Comment: Yeah... agreed. "Thanks" and "please" are not entirely needed, but what about manners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell cannot identify the ~ symbol in script which running instead of ~ use $HOME to use the original value.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is expanded to home directory; `~/test/file.1` is expanded to something like `/home/username/test/file.1`.

To denote `~` literally, use single quotation: `'~/test/file.1'`.

```
$ echo ~/test
/home/falsetru/test
$ echo '~/test'
~/test
$ echo '~'/test
~/test
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that you can also use $HOME variable.

for Example :

cat $HOME/test/file.1

$HOME is the environment variable. /home/user